# Not getting all the methods from Azure Storage package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure

So I'm trying to play around with Queues in Azure storage so I created a Console application and added the WindowsAzure.Storage package in NuGet. Then I put this bit of code in and it works it creates a queue for me.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connection = "myConnectionString......";
        CloudStorageAccount storageAcc = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connection);

        CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAcc.CreateCloudQueueClient();
        CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("myQueue");
        queue.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

However there should be a non Async version I can call instead

```
        queue.CreateIfNotExists();
```

But Visual Studio 2017 is not recognising CreateIfNotExists as a member of CloudQueue.

If I try to build it it throws a compile error.

I seems like lots of non Async methods are missing such as AddMessage and GetMessage any idea what could cause this?

Comment: If you're using .Net Core, then it is a known issue. Sync methods are not implemented in .Net Core version of the SDK.

Comment: Is there any documentation or blog posts about using the SDK with .NET Core?

Comment: Same as .Net ones. Only thing you’ve to keep in mind is to make use of async methods only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I seems like lots of non Async methods are missing such as AddMessage and GetMessage any idea what could cause this?

According to your description, I suppose you created a Console .NET Core project.  I have created a simple demo, the result  like [this](https://image.ibb.co/d7wxGH/queuenuget.gif). This .NET Core project just supports the Async methods.There is no these sync methods now. So you haven't missed these methods.

If you just want to use sync methods like queue.CreateIfNotExists(), I suggest you could choose Console App(.NET Framework) project and install the WindowsAzure.Storage package to try again. Or you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues) to use Azure queue.